# PHP selenium how to send keys ctrl + s for saving a web page

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver

Can i save a web page with this driver?
I'm trying to save this by <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> but my script didn't work.
I tried with following codes:

```
$this->webDriver->action()->keyDown(null, WebDriverKeys::CONTROL)->sendKeys(null, 's');
```

and

```
$this->webDriver->getKeyboard()->pressKey(WebDriverKeys::LEFT_CONTROL)->sendKeys('s');
```

What's the solution?

**Php-webdriver version:** 1.5
**PHP version:** 5.6.31
**Selenium server version:** 3.7.1
**Operating system:** windows
**Browser used + version:** chrome v62

Comment: Is this a testing scenario or do you just want to save the page? If the latter, you may prefer wget: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049632/saving-full-page-content-using-selenium

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving full page content using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049632/saving-full-page-content-using-selenium)